# Flickering fill issue on SVG hover

Tags: html, css, svg

New to SVG thing.
I have a created a SVG shape using Illustrator and inserted an image tag inside that shave. After `svg` tag, have added some html, which is hidden by default and shown when user hovers over the svg.
But doing so, i'm facing of image/color flickering. Try hovering over the SVG.

and suggest some better way to achieve this.

```css
.svg-parent {
  position: relative;
}
.svg-parent svg {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}
.svg-parent svg:hover + .svg-child {
  display: block;
}
.svg-parent path:hover {
  fill: #fff802;
}
.svg-child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-parent">
  <svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 302 395" xml:space="preserve" width="302" height="395">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="america" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="302" height="395">
        <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNQ3H.png" width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" />
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <g>
      <path d="M0,0h302l-1,330L0,395V0z" fill="url(#america)" />
    </g>
  </svg>
  <div class="svg-child">This text and image flicker, when you move your mouse cursor around this svg shape</div>
</div>
```

[image: image inserted inside svg tag]

Answer (score 2):

Your `svg-child` overlaps the `svg`. Its stacked above the image with z-index while its display is solely dependant on hovering over the svg. That is the reason **your mouse events switch between states**.

When the pointer enters the element for the first time, the hover triggers the display and path fill. But when you move, its no longer pointing at the `svg`, instead its pointing at the `svg-child`, since its placed higher by the `z-index`. This happens multiple times thereby causing the flicker.

**Clip path method**: For browser support check [Caniuse = css-clip-path](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path)

```css
.svg-parent {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
 -webkit-clip-path: url(#clip);
  clip-path: url(#clip);
}

.svg-child {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.svg-child a {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.svg-child:hover a {
  visibility: visible;
}

.svg-child:hover + svg path {
  fill: #fff802;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-parent">
  <div class="svg-child">
    <a href>Your Link</a>
  </div>
  <svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 302 395" xml:space="preserve" width="302" height="395">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="america" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="302" height="395">
        <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNQ3H.png" width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" />
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <g>
      <path d="M0,0h302l-1,330L0,395V0z" fill="url(#america)" />
    </g>
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="clip">
        <path d="M0,0h302l-1,330L0,395V0z"/>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</div>
```

You can also just use [**SVG Anchor Element `<a>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/a) this way to add a link on the svg.

```
<a xlink:href="https://www.example.org"
 target="_blank">
  <path d="M0,0h302l-1,330L0,395V0z" fill="url(#america)" />      
  <text x="20" y="20">Click On This SVG</text>
</a>
```

Here is a working example of that. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zdw4Ldjn/3/)

*Add CSS to position the link text as you see fit.*

Comment: This is because, I want the show yellow section, only when SVG is hovered. in your scenario, if user hover overs the bottom-right side(which is not SVG), then also the yellow section triggers. That is why I went for `svg:hover + .svg-child`

Comment: You will have to change your stacking context. if you are planning to stick with `svg:hover + svg-child` then apply `pointer-events:none` to `svg-child` .. it will disable all mouse actions on it.

Comment: this is great, it removes the flickr, but issue is I have `anchor` links inside this `svg-child` and can't have `pointer-events:none` due to that.

Comment: fixed post to accomodate that. I changed the stacking and structure. Do check.

Comment: Great approach for that. but still, `clip-path` lacks IE support. :(

Comment: You can also add an anchor element to your SVG. I am gonna leave it at that. Edited it way too many times.